# Do I need shielding on a long, power-only USB cable?

Tags: emc

I want to use a long, 3m USB cable to power a board with an ESP32 WROOM module. Power draw is less than 100 mA.

I am not using the data pins on the USB cable.

If the cable is NOT shielded, should I expect issues with EMC?

I need to be FCC compliant (FCC Part 15)

The board goes into sleep and wakes up regularly, so the current drawn isn't totally constant.

Comment: i would put a "decoupling" cap on the esp32 to keep wire residence from causing a brown-out during high-current bursts of wifi traffic. A 470u will chop the spikes down by half, a 1000u all but eliminates them. Also add a modest ~(0.01u-1) uceramic or poly cap to soak up RF/EMI. Also clamp a snap-around rf choke on the esp-end of the usb cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a shield is needed.  You want to make sure the power leads are twisted.  You also might want to make provisions for a common mode (CM) choke.  While the power is DC, there may be some high frequency noise on the power lines from the power supply (don't know what that is).  It only takes a small amount (5 uA?) of common mode current to fail an FCC part 15 test.

**Answers to OP's Questions**

1. No.  I was suggesting that you make provisions to put a common mode choke around the USB cable, close to the PS, to be added if you fail EMC testing (radiated emissions).  If I knew more about the internal pf the power supply you're using, I might be able to make a more definitive recommendation.
2. Twisting power leads (hot + return) is, in my mind, just good design practice.  It may not be absolutely needed, but it doesn't cost anything (or very little) to do this.

Comment: The common mode choke would be part of the power supply? So what you are saying is that I should be using a good power supply?

Comment: What kind of disturbance does the twisting counteract? Disturbance coming from the power supply, or disturbance coming back from the device?

Comment: I am still undecided on which power supply to include on the package, if any. So I have the option to choose a high-quality one.

Comment: With having a twisted cable - I have not found any suppliers so far who provide assembled usb power cables that are twisted. But I am probably not looking in the right places.

Comment: So why not just use a standard shielded USB cable and be done with it?

Comment: This may be what I end up going with.